# VirtualBox 5 on Yosemite with Windows 8 guest - is higher resolution than 1280x800 possible?

Tags: virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox 5 on Yosemite and I've created fresh Image with Windows 8. In full screen I can only select 1280x800 which is way below my retina display.

I've tried disabling 3D Acceleration, reinstalling add-ons, increasing video RAM, or executing commands like:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "win81" CustomVideoMode1 1920x1080x32
VBoxManage controlvm "win81" setvideomodehint 1920 1080 32
```

and noting .... stil 1280x800

Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Installed Guest Additions?

Comment: yes - I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run those commands, you'll need to enable the commands to work, using the following:

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any
```

Once that has been run, you may now execute the following to switch your VM to the resolution you want. *NOTE:* Your VM "win81" must be running when you execute this command on your Mac's command line/Terminal.

```
VBoxManage controlvm "win81" setvideomodehint 1920 1080 32
```